# what is the exception: "TemplateDoesNotExist at /myapp/form" in Django project

Tags: python, django

I created Django project, using html- form.

the form.html:

```
<form action = "" method = "get">
    <label for="your_name">Your name: </label>
    <input id="your_name" type="text" name="your_name">
    <input type="submit" value="OK">
</form>
```

the views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def dateform(request):
     return render(request, 'templates/form.html' )
```

the urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [

    path('form', views.dateform,name = 'form')

]
```

the setting.py:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

When I run the project in this URL: http://localhost:8000/myapp/form
I get an error:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /myapp/form
templates/form.html
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/myapp/form
Django Version: 3.1
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
templates/form.html
Exception Location: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py, line 19, in get_template
Python Executable:  C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe
Python Version: 3.8.3
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\smarti\\myproject',
 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\smarti\\myproject',
 'C:\\Program Files\\JetBrains\\PyCharm '
 '2020.2\\plugins\\python\\helpers\\pycharm_display',
 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\python38.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32',
 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python38\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Program Files\\JetBrains\\PyCharm '
 '2020.2\\plugins\\python\\helpers\\pycharm_matplotlib_backend']
Server time:    Sat, 08 Aug 2020 20:03:51 +0000
```

What is the problem? I must your help necessary!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you show where the template is located in relation to your whole project? (If forced to guess, I'd say you might have it in a top-level `templates` directory - if so, you either need a further `templates` directory within it that contains the template, or to change the path from `templates/form.html` to simply `form.html`.)

Comment: thanks! it's working:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your views, remove `template/` from the return so it is just `return render(request, 'forms.html')`

Django will know where to find the templates.

Answer (score 0):

It's a custom to create a folder or directory with the app name that way you can place all your html files to that folder and reference it in your view from there.

So inside your  template  you will  have the app name and then the html files in it

def home (request) :
return render (request, "appname/index.html")